# How do i display and disable checkboxes based from my response's row and column?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a cinema seat plan design with vue and I'm having a hard time making the layout of the seats.

I have this in my vue component:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(item,index) in seatRows" :key="index">
     <div v-for="(rows,i) in item" :key="i" :id="rows.Row">
          <input type="checkbox">
      </div>                         
</div>
```

My json looks like this

```
      "Seats":[
         {
            "ID":1,
            "Name":"A08",
            "Status":"0",
            "Row":1,
            "Col":1
         },
         {
            "ID":2,
            "Name":"A07",
            "Status":"0",
            "Row":1,
            "Col":2
         },
         {
            "ID":3,
            "Name":"A06",
            "Status":"0",
            "Row":1,
            "Col":4
         },
         {
            "ID":4,
            "Name":"A05",
            "Status":"0",
            "Row":1,
            "Col":5
         },
         {
            "ID":5,
            "Name":"A04",
            "Status":"0",
            "Row":1,
            "Col":6
         },
         {
            "ID":6,
            "Name":"A03",
            "Status":"0",
            "Row":1,
            "Col":7
         }

      ],
   }
}
```

With my code, i can display the necessary checkboxes but i need to have a blank space or a disabled checkbox in "Row":1 "Column": 3 which is missing from the response.

How do i do this ?

Comment: ` "Row":1 "Column": 3 which is missing from the response.` means u dont get it from  ur api response right ? 
if that u should check the code which is responsible of sent seats data
and show us that code otherwise cant help

Comment: @sayalok Hi, I'm getting api from a third party so i can't change the structure of the response. I'm trying to figure out how to i make a disabled checkbox or a spacer on row 1 column 3

Answer (score 1):

Try calling a function from within checkboxes and pass arguments to calculate when being rendered

```
  <input type="checkbox" v-bind:disabled="isToDisable(key, id)">
```

Then create a method

```
  isToDisable(key, id){
    console.log(key)
    var isDisabled = true; // check if row and col is in object
    return isDisabled;
  }
```